# how to find and replace text url with links in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to find text url  in my editor and convert them to anchor tag links using jquery.

here is my code

```
function urlify(text) {
        var urlRegex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;
        return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
        })  
    }



 $("#queEditor").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    var url = urlify($("#queEditor").text);
    console.log(url);
 });
```

But it's giving an error undefined function text. Could someone help me rectify this?

Comment: Simple typo. Change `text` to `text()`

Comment: what is element with  is `queEditor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `.text()` is a function you need to use `()` when you want to invoke it.

```
$("#queEditor").text(); //Notice ()
```