# Convert website links dynamically to anchor tags in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I want to add anchor tags to the website links which are in my div.
For example bellow text is in my div

```
<div>I am Harsha Vardhan working for SSoft Pvt Ltd and its website is ssoft.com . My personal website is hv.com .</div>
```

In the above text I want to show `ssoft.com` and `hv.com` in anchor tags which suppose to open in new tabs while clicking. My text may contain any number of website links.

Comment: I short, you want to create an hyperlink ? the `<a>` tag is at the core of HTML. Read any html tutorial to find the answer.

Comment: @Derlin I think, OP wants to dynamically enclose all web links in <a> tags.

Comment: What @SudiptaMondal said is correct, I want to enclose all web links dynamically or through a simple function...

Comment: Do you have only `.com` domain in string?

Comment: It may be anything, I mean any domain...

Comment: This will be tricky as text may contain many combinations, you will need to suggest a pattern of web links appearing to look for regex options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Took reference from [how to find and replace text url with links in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410243/how-to-find-and-replace-text-url-with-links-in-jquery)

```js
function urlify(text) {
        var urlRegex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;
        return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            return '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
        })  
    }

 var array = $("#originalText").text().split(' '), array1="";
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
     array1+=urlify(array[i])+" ";
     
    }
    $("#modifiedText").html(array1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="originalText">I am Harsha Vardhan working for SSoft Pvt Ltd and its website is www.ssoft.com . My personal website is www.hv.co .</div>

<div id="modifiedText"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can find target link from string. The javascript [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) find every link and replace it with anchor tag.

```js
$("div").html(function(i, html){
  return html.replace(/(\w+\.\w+)/g, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I am Harsha Vardhan working for SSoft Pvt Ltd and its website is ssoft.com . My personal website is hv.com .</div>
```